# Ubuntu - How to open terminal using shortcut key and do alt+tab

Tags: 14.04

I am using citrix to rdp to ubuntu GUI interface . Using mouse opetations are bit slow for me.

1. I want to check on how to open terminal using a shortcut key .
2. How to fo ALT + TAB in ubuntu .
3. for paste, I have to right click and then choose 'paste' from the option .

Basic Ubuntu commands.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/  *You've tagged your release as being 14.04; is that correct?*

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu

1. A shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) is enabled by default to launch a terminal. The shortcut can optionally be changed or deleted in Settings - Keyboard
2. To ALT + TAB in Ubuntu, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. There are by default two system wide shortcut keys to paste text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

If one or another does not work on your system, then it is not due to the operating system. Look for the issues in your "citrix to rdp to ubuntu GUI interface".